# Why crashes UISearchBar after reload TableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, objective-c-blocks

I have tableView with `UISearchBarDisplayController`. The below code was fetch record from webserver and display the `tableview` cell every works fine. but when will scroll 3 or 5 time downwards and upwards through i will going to click search bar it will crash the crash report `NSLog` doesn't print anything.

Remember i tried `NSZombie` , breaking point,exception point etc., but nothing helps.

Important question:

How to load data to `tableview` after fetched data from webserver. because `tableview` delegates methods are called before fetching data from server.

```
 DataFetchController *getDataFetch=[[DataFetchController alloc]init];
    //getleadFetch.delegate=self;
    [getDataFetch beginTaskWithCallbackBlock:^(NSArray *mm){


        [self.tableView reloadData];//if i comment this line the UISearchBar not crashes 


    }];
```

Comment: one thing to make sure of is that you are calling `[self.tableView reloadData]` on the main (UI) thread. Can't tell from what you posted if that is your only issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update tableview data in main thread it not crash.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading the tableview before the data fetch is complete will obviously result in a crash.
So to avoid that we need to know when the data fetch is complete.
This can be easily obtained from your sql apis which return an error code when the fetch is complete. You can via that to find out if the fetching is complete or not.So sequentially you can provide the reloading of your table view command.
Hope it helps!!

Comment: "Loading the tableview before the data fetch is complete will obviously result in a crash" - not necessarily. It depends what the code in his delegate methods do. They might just do calls to a nil object which silently causes the table to appear empty (with no crash).